# Extract plan from Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

How do I retrieve the Plan ID in Rails from Stripe's invoice.payment_succeeded webhook event?

I have tried the code below but keep on getting plan is nil error.

```
plan_id = event.data.object.lines.data[1].plan.id
```

Here is the web hook event.

```
{
  "id"=>"evt_111111111",
  "created"=>1207343135,
  "livemode"=>true,
  "type"=>"invoice.payment_succeeded",
  "data"=>{
    "object"=>{
      "date"=>2437418246,
      "id"=>"in_......",
      "period_start"=>1406044997,
      "period_end"=>1437238559,
      "lines"=>{
        "object"=>"list",
        "total_count"=>1,
        "has_more"=>false,
        "url"=>"/v1/invoices/in_...../lines",
        "data"=>[
          {
            "id"=>"sub_.....",
            "object"=>"line_item",
            "type"=>"subscription",
            "livemode"=>true,
            "amount"=>29900,
            "currency"=>"cad",
            "proration"=>false,
            "period"=>{
              "start"=>2437418246,
              "end"=>2437418246
            },
            "quantity"=>1,
            "plan"=>{
              "interval"=>"month",
              "name"=>"Business",
              "created"=>2437446,
              "amount"=>19900,
              "currency"=>"cad",
              "id"=>"P3",
              "object"=>"plan",
              "livemode"=>true,
              "interval_count"=>1,
              "trial_period_days"=>7,
              "metadata"=>{},
              "statement_description"=>nil
            },
            "description"=>nil,
            "metadata"=>{}
          }
        ],
        "count"=>1
      },
      "subtotal"=>19900,
      "total"=>19900,
      "customer"=>"cus_.....",
      "object"=>"invoice",
      "attempted"=>true,
      "closed"=>true,
      "forgiven"=>false,
      "paid"=>true,
      "livemode"=>true,
      "attempt_count"=>1,
      "amount_due"=>19900,
      "currency"=>"cad",
      "starting_balance"=>0,
      "ending_balance"=>0,
      "next_payment_attempt"=>nil,
      "webhooks_delivered_at"=>14022ert61,
      "charge"=>"ch_......",
      "discount"=>nil,
      "application_fee"=>nil,
      "subscription"=>"sub_......",
      "metadata"=>{},
      "statement_description"=>nil,
      "description"=>nil
    }
  },
  "object"=>"event",
  "pending_webhooks"=>1,
  "request"=>nil,
  "webhook"=>{
    "id"=>"evt_....."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to only have a single item in the `data` list.

Note that Arrays in Ruby start at index `0`.

I believe you will want to change `data[1]` to `data[0]`.

**Note**, this can still break if there is a chance that the `data` list can be empty.